# USB ports not working on new Motherboard with Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers

Today I bought new [Asus H410M-K](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/PRIME-H410M-K/) motherboard. BIOS and Ubuntu works normally with USB, but as soon as Windows 7 loads I loose all power to USB ports - none of them are working.

There are no such drivers in manufacturers page, I tried BIOS upgrade though. Intel® USB 3.0 eXtensible Host Controller Driver setup won't even launch - bad hardware or something. I tried drivers from other MB - nothing.

After some playing I moved USB controller in Device Manager from Other Devices to USB controller, but still no driver for Generic USB hub. Tried BIOS settings for Legacy and Hand-Off.

Does it mean I will have to live with PS2 keyboard and mouse and with no USB flash drives? The only way is to move to Windows 10?

As I understand only hope is to find proper driver... Does anyone have any idea where to get one?

Comment: The spec says "Windows® 10 64-bit". Windows 7 is out of support.

Comment: @DavidPostill indeed the documentation says "Operating SystemWindows® 10 - 64 bit"
but OP says that UBUNTU works normally, the issue is a bios setting.

Comment: https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1013649 check this link from the FAQ of the model of your motherboard

Comment: {sigh} OP is trying to use Windows 7, which is not supported by this motherboard.